# Resize PCM array without resample

Tags: c, audio, pcm

I receive PCM byte array with sample rate 8 kHz and length 320 from network.

Now I want to resize the length of array to be 2<sup>n</sup>, i.e. 256 or 512 while keeping the sample rate at 8 kHz.

Does anyone know an algorithm can do this?

Comment: Just chop the array.

Comment: When you resize, do you just want to add silence, or do you want to stretch out the sound somehow to fit?

Comment: @Phil Freihofner: I want to fit the new size, not add silence.

Comment: Tactics to take depend on the results that you want. If a sound is N frames long and you want it to be N+M, and there is no additional material to just tack on, then the sounds can be stretched either with pitch preservation (more difficult, involves breaking sound into "granules" that are repeated and possibly blended) or allows the pitch to drop (usually done using linear interpolation to get more samples from the "implied" audio wave). I or others can fill in more details if you indicate which approach you want to take.

Comment: @Phil Freihofner: The second approach seems more easier and popular. Could you give me some tips or example. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume the data is a series of PCM values, ranging from -1 to 1. (For 16-bit encoding, the sound values might actually be -32768 to 32767, or the range of a Short.)

Array A has the data, Array B is the destination.
If A.length = 320, and B.length = 256, then the following should work:

```
float incr = B.length / (float) A.length;
for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
    B[i] = linearInterpolation(A, incr * i);
}
```

To do linear interpolation, let's say incr * i [0.8 * 3] calculates to some value in between n and n+1, e.g., 2.4 (between 2 and 3). First, get the fractional part (0.4):

```
fract = i * incr - (int)(i * incr);
```

then calculate as follows:

```
return ( (A[n] * (1 - fract)) + (A[n+1] * (fract)) ) / 2;
```

You may have to encode/decode to PCM from the bytes. That is a separate issue, but it has been dealt with on StackOverflow several times.

Comment: Sorry for my stupidity. In this case incr = 0.8, How to get value 2.75 from n = 2, and n = i? Thanks.

Comment: Sorry for not keeping the example consistent. I edited my answer so that the incr will be an actual value derived from your sample case. I hope that makes things clearer!